# Error while trying to connect my Express app with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I've almost finished my app and I want to connect my MongoDB database to the serverless platform MongoDB Atlas. Until then, I've been using my database in localhost (with mongosh) and it worked perfectly fine. Now I've changed "mongodb://localhost" to the adress of my database and I get an error : *MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation*

Here is my code in db-connection.js :

```
require('dotenv').config();
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

function connect(collection) {
    let client = new MongoClient(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@calendrier-delle.2rqpi.mongodb.net/calendrierdelle?retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
    client.connect();
    let calendrierDelle = client.db('calendrierdelle');
    let collections = calendrierDelle.collection(`${collection}`);

    return collections;
}

module.exports = { connect };
```

And a snippet of my code in server.js :

```
require('dotenv').config();
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let dbConnection = require("./db-connection.js");

//Here is an example of how I make an query
let query = dbConnection.connect("aCollection").find({
   something: (some value),
}).toArray();
query.then((data) => { /* Do something with the data */ });
```

To precise :

• I don't use mongoose because I don't really need, and I'm lazy to change lol.

• On MongoDB Atlas, I've added an IP adress 0.0.0.0/0

• My username and password are goods

• Here is a screenshot of my cluster's name and db's name[image: MongoDB Atlas]

In my code to connect with my database, I don't really understand why at the end of the url I connect my app with the database, and after I have to do the same thing : client.db('calendrierdelle'). I think here is my problem but I don't know how to solve it : I've tried everything (changing url, omit my calendrierDelle variable etc...).

Can you help me please ? Thanks !

PS : sorry I've added a mongoose tag to that post, I don't use it, but it's pretty close to my problem.

Comment: `calendrierDelle.collection(`${collection}`);` (with the string template) isn't necessary if the connection parameter is a string (which it always should be). You could just do this: `calendrierDelle.collection(collection);`; it's faster anyways. Also if the connect function is passed an unexpected datatype it'll probably throw instead of causing you hours of frustration trying to connect to the `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous), meaning actions don't wait for the action before it to finish. You tried to do stuff on the database without waiting for MongoDB to connect. Fortunately, MongoDB doesn't make it too hard with Promises, and `async`/`await`. You can make things "wait" for Mongo to connect like so:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

async function connect(collection) {
    let client = new MongoClient(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@calendrier-delle.2rqpi.mongodb.net/calendrierdelle?retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
    await client.connect();
    let calendrierDelle = client.db('calendrierdelle');
    let collections = calendrierDelle.collection(`${collection}`);

    return collections;
}

module.exports = { connect };
```

Notice the `await` in front of `client.connect()`. Also notice that the connect function has `async` in front of it. Until the lastest versions of NodeJS, await must be in an async function.

Comment: It works thanks ! But now I have another problem, as it is a promise, my code in server.js doesn't work. I've tried to resolve the promise with .then but doesn't work... Is there a way to resolve the promise before doing some stuff with the database ? (resolve `dbConnection.connect("aCollection"` and before doing the stuff like `.find()`)

Comment: Update : it works, but it's hell : I already used a lot of .then, now I have 2x more, my code will be unreadable if I change all of my code. Any solution please ?

Comment: @Xeway `.then()` can be replaced with `await`. So create an `async function` and instead of something like `doSomething().then(result => somethingElse(result).then(anotherResult => /* ... */))` you can do something like `const result = await doSomething(); const anotherResult = await doSomethingElse(result);`. Or you could just use promise chaining: `doSomething().then(result => { /* do stuff */ return result; }).then(result => { /* do other stuff */ return result; }).then(console.log);`. A simple Google Search will show you lots.

Answer (score 0):

```
require('dotenv').config();
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = 
`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_USER_PASSWORD}@
${process.env.DB_CLUSTER}.mongodb.net`;

async function connectDatabase() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const db = client.db("main");

return {
    listings: db.collection("test_listings")
  };
};

module.exports = { connectDatabase };
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. Regular functions != arrow functions.

Comment: Correction done.